# Laravel 5.1 login form

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

I'm putting together a small web app using Laravel 5.1.

However whenever I submit the login form (1) rather than being redirect( which is set) or some form of error data being returned the same form is displayed again with no errors or useful response to help diagnose why authentication isn't taking place.

Any suggestions would be gratefully accepted.

1

```
   {!!Form::open(array('method'=>'POST','action'=>'Auth\AuthController@postLogin'))!!}
    <div class="form-group">
    {!!Form::label('Email','Email')!!}
    {!!Form::email('Email',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    {!!Form::label('Password','Password')!!}
    {!!Form::password('Password',['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    {!!Form::label('Remember Me', 'Remember Me')!!}
    {!!Form::checkbox('Remember me',null,null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    {!!Form::submit('login',['class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control'])!!}
```

Route.php

```
    // ...
    Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');

    Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

   Route::controllers([
  'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

Comment: Can you please enable debug in laravel? And does your php logs shows you something?

Comment: Debug was on, nothing was shown in logs. 
@ThomasKim 's answer below was correct, looking back it is a very simple mistake coming from being tiered and new with the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input names are wrong. The first argument for a lot of the `FormBuilder`'s methods is your input name. It's not the text that's being displayed, and they are case-sensitive so it should be like this:

```
{!!Form::open(array('method'=>'POST','action'=>'Auth\AuthController@postLogin'))!!}
<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('email','Email')!!}
{!!Form::email('email',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
{!!Form::label('password','Password')!!}
{!!Form::password('password',['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
{!!Form::label('remember', 'Remember Me')!!}
{!!Form::checkbox('remember',null,null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
{!!Form::submit('login',['class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control'])!!}
```

If you didn't close your form, you should also add that to the end too.

```
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

As for why you are not seeing any error messages, that's hard for me to say without seeing the code that's displaying your view.

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas, I've been figurativly banging my head with this one over the afternoon.
One of those things that needs someone else to review your code

Form close was off the bottom, missed it in the copy paste.

Comment: I'm glad I can help. :)